# Git: cloning with shared local storage (using hard links)

Tags: git

I'd like to make it easy for a large number of devs to *repeatedly* clone a very large and remote git repo. Some sort of local per-user 'caching' is necessary. There are obviously lots of ways to do this, I'm just surprised that it seems as if the one way that would seem most natural to me does not exist in git.

Is there an industry standard practice on this?
Is there some git option that I'm just misunderstanding?

Ideal solution

```
#first clone - very slow.
git clone ssh://remote.repo/repo.git repo1
#subsequent clones - lightning fast
git clone --shared-with-hard-links repo1 ssh://remote.repo/repo.git repo2
```

In this imaginary solution, there is no `.git/objects/info/alternates` created, objects are just shared on clone using hard links, like rsync's `--link-dest` option, or like git's clone when the repo is on the local filesystem.

The alternatives I see, are none of them that attractive:

1. I can do `git clone --reference repo1 ssh://remote.repo/repo.git repo2` which relies on repo1 existing and if repo1 is deleted, then repo2 is fubared.
2. I can do `git clone --dissociate --reference repo1 ssh://remote.repo/repo.git repo2` but storage is not shared so now I've used up twice the storage I want, and it's probably still relatively slow for that reason.
3. There are various hacks of varying complexity that may need wrappers around cloning and pulling. The complexity is, compared to real programming, obviously trivial, but running your SCM under a bunch of wrappers is just a nuisance that should really be avoided.

   - Store a git 'cache' repo in a central location on each dev's PC and have a wrapper around clone to automatically fetch on the cache first and then `clone --reference <cache>`.
   - Remember every clone that is done and subsequent clones will look for a pre-existing local clone and clone locally from that (creating hard links) and then fix up the remotes after that. Roughly, it goes something like this:

.

```
#find any existing clones... repo1
git clone /path/to/repo1 repo2
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin ssh://remote.repo/repo.git
git fetch
#Abandon any local changes made in the other workspace
for ref in $(git --git-dir "$gitdir" for-each-ref  refs/heads --format "%(refname)" ) ; do
    refbase=$(basename $ref)
    run_cmd git --git-dir "$gitdir" update-ref $ref remotes/origin $refbase
done
```

But it all seems like a hack. Surely there's a better way?

Thanks,
Mort

Notes:

- We actually do have a LAN-local mirror. The repo is large enough, that we need better than just that to achieve reasonable clone speeds.
- The repo is big. 11 min to clone over GigE and up to 40 min if the user is on Windows.

**Update**

The best thing that I can figure out to do is to have a cache in `/var/cache/git/<repo_name>.git` that is a `clone --mirror` of the central repo. New clones use the `--shared` option to both reduce space/time in the initial clone and to speed up subsequent `fetch`es. There is a wrapper script to `clone` a new workspace that does this:

```
git --git-dir /var/cache/git/<repo_name>.git remote update
git clone --shared /var/cache/git/<repo_name>.git
git remote set-url origin ssh://remote.repo/repo.git
```

I would have preferred something that relied on hard links because they are immune to issues if objects are somehow removed from the shared cache. But I guess that does not exist.

Comment: Interesting read: https://github.com/git/git/commit/908700c0082487f9c859b951370148ff7e8acb97 (for the upcoming Git 2.7)

Answer (score 3):

Git does hardlink by default when you clone a local repository. So, you can

```
git clone /path/to/repo /path/to/clone
cd /path/to/clone
git remote add upstream http://example.com/path/to/repo/to/clone
git fetch upstream
```

But this has a number of disadvantages:

- The next `git gc` will break hardlinks and eat your disk space.
- This will work only if `/path/to/repo` and `/path/to/clone` are on the same partition.
- You have to be careful with the tools you use on the result, e.g. a `rsync` without `-H` will copy all hardlinks.

  I think the `.git/objects/info/alternates` is much better in most cases.

Comment: That's essentially my last example restated. I suspect that if `/path/to/repo` has local unpushed changes on master, your list of steps will also require a `git reset --hard upstream/master` to work. Users will have to remember to fetch and push to upstream, or they will have to do more steps to change their origin URL, every time they make a new workspace. I'm not trying to be nitpicky beyond saying that it could be a hassle every time you just want a new workspace. For a solution using `.git/objects/info/alternates` I think I favour having something central and pristine in `/var/cache/git/`.