# git clone --reference, but with hardlinks

Tags: git, clone

I like how `git clone --reference` saves both network capacity and disk space. However, if the reference repo is deleted, the new repo gets corrupted.

As far as I understand `--reference` uses `.git/objects/info/alternates` to share the objects. However, if it used hardlinks instead, like `--local` does, then there wouldn't be such a problem—it could save network capacity, disk space, and wouldn't get corrupted when reference repository is deleted.

Is there a way to achieve such effect?

Comment: Not at all the same (doesn't use links) but `--dissociate` makes reference clones save only network bandwidth. It would be nice if it combined nicely with `--local` but I don't think it does.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30161858/2303202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following script to achieve that. First time it is run it will create a cache repo which is a mirror of the remote repo. Consequently it will use this cache to make a `--local` clone (with all the benefits of hard links and saving network capacity), then it overwrites the `origin` to be the remote repo, instead of the local cache repo.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Usage: clone <branch> [<target-directory-name>]
#
set -ueo pipefail

readonly BRANCH=$1
readonly TARGET=${2:-$BRANCH}

readonly ORIGIN_REPO='git@...'
readonly CACHE_REPO='/tmp/cache-repo.git'

if [[ -e "$CACHE_REPO" ]]; then
  echo "Updating existing cache repo at: $CACHE_REPO"
  git --git-dir="$CACHE_REPO" remote update --prune
else
  echo "Creating cache repo from scratch"
  git clone --bare --mirror "$ORIGIN_REPO" "$CACHE_REPO"
fi

git clone --local "$CACHE_REPO" "$TARGET" --branch="$BRANCH"
git --git-dir="$TARGET/.git" remote set-url origin "$ORIGIN_REPO"
```